# How do you format GWT Datepicker month label?

Tags: java, gwt, datepicker

I am wondering if there is anyone who knows how to format the `datepickerMonth` for a GWT datepicker?

The current format is `2020 Jan` and I am looking for it to be `January 2020`.

I've gone through the GWT Datepicker Javadoc, but could not find any way to access that value.

I am using GWT 2.8.1.

Comment: use a `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @YCF_L I understand how to format dates, but not specifically that value. As I do not see a way to access it

Comment: like you, i took a look at the javadoc, but it is not configurable it appears

Comment: @RobNewton My guy says there should be a way, but maybe not. Thanks for double checking for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do that in GWT 2.7. I believe it will work in 2.8 too - if not, please, let me know.

If you look at the implementation of `DatePicker` you'll see that it uses `DefaultMonthSelector`, `DefaultCalendarView` and `CalendarModel`.

`CalendarModel` is what we are interested in because it provides `monthAndYearFormatter` which is responsible for rendering `2020 Jan`. Unfortunately, you can not set your own `CalendarModel`, so we need to subclass `DatePicker`.

The `getMonthAndYearFormatter()` method returns `PredefinedFormat.YEAR_MONTH_ABBR` and we need to change it to `PredefinedFormat.YEAR_MONTH` to get full month name. Or change it to whatever you want.

So, you just need to override this method like this:

```
public class MyDatePicker extends DatePicker {
    public MyDatePicker() {
        super(new DefaultMonthSelector(), new DefaultCalendarView(), new CalendarModel() {
            @Override
            protected DateTimeFormat getMonthAndYearFormatter() {
                return DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.YEAR_MONTH);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just use `MyDatePicker` instead of `DatePicker`.

---

And this is the result:

[image: DatePicker with custom monthAndYearFormatter]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't even considered doing this. I was able to add it into my code very easily.